# How do I cast a XElement as string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, casting, linq-to-xml, xelement

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn4 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=test_BdbCSSQL01;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
conn4.Open();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM ERROROfSIDESStagingOUT";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn4);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
DataRow dr;
dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XmlString.xml");
XNamespace ns = "https://uidataexchange.org/schemas";

var node = doc.Descendants(ns + "EmployerTPASeparationResponse");
var node2 = node.ElementAt(i);

        foreach (var param in node2.Elements())
        {

            try
            {
                if (dr[param.Name.LocalName].ToString() == "PriorIncidentOccurrence")
                {
                    var PriorIncidentDescendants = param.Descendants(ns + "PriorIncidentOccurrence");
                    dr["PriorIncidentID"] = PriorIncidentDescendants.ElementAt(0).Value;                                        
                }

                if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains(param.Name.LocalName))
                {
                    dr[param.Name.LocalName] = param.Value;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                //TODO: SendMail
                string asdf = ee.ToString();
            }
        }
        SqlCommandBuilder sb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Update(dt);

if (conn4 != null)
{
    conn4.Close();
}
```

I am trying to cast `dr[param.Name.LocalName]` as type string. Both of the following do not work.

```
(string)dr[param.Name.LocalName]
dr[param.Name.LocalName].ToString()
```

Comment: But what do you need? The nested text node in such XElement or serialize the XElement so you get an XML fragment?

Comment: @Matias:  I am trying to cast dr[param.Name.LocalName] to type string.

Comment: I repeat the same question, because it seems you're not very sure of what result you want of this "cast"..?

Comment: You can't 'cast' a non-string into a string.

Comment: You're not trying to cast an XElement, you're trying to cast an element of a DataRow, which is an object. What is it giving you so far?

Comment: @Inuyasha, that's not technically correct. You can create a type that is castable to string. Although it's not usual and you certainly can't do it the way OP wants it to do.

Comment: @svick, how can this be done?

Comment: @Inuyasha, see [Using Conversion Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my guess, that you are calling `dr[param.Name.LocalName]` before you have assigned a value to that key in your first `if` statement.

You should probably state the error you recieve. I'm guessing it has nothing to do with casting...

You could try to check the value of `param.Name.LocalName` in the debugger (or print it with `Debug.WriteLine`) and make sure that the values are all valid column names in your `DataRow`.